# Using Postgres to return a selection based on frequency distribution

Tags: postgresql, statistics

I am not even sure if this is a possibility so my apologies if I'm barking up the wrong tree; I am ignorant of Postgres's limitations as I am self-taught.

This is hypothetical, but if I had a table like so:

**dice_rolls**

| roll_1 | roll_2 | sum |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 1 | 3 | 4 |
| 1 | 4 | 5 |
| 1 | 5 | 6 |
| 1 | 6 | 7 |
| 2 | 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 2 | 4 |
| 2 | 3 | 5 |
| 2 | 4 | 6 |
| 2 | 5 | 7 |
| 2 | 6 | 8 |
| 3 | 1 | 4 |
| 3 | 2 | 5 |
| 3 | 3 | 6 |
| 3 | 4 | 7 |
| 3 | 5 | 8 |
| 3 | 6 | 9 |
| 4 | 1 | 5 |
| 4 | 2 | 6 |
| 4 | 3 | 7 |
| 4 | 4 | 8 |
| 4 | 5 | 9 |
| 4 | 6 | 10 |
| 5 | 1 | 6 |
| 5 | 2 | 7 |
| 5 | 3 | 8 |
| 5 | 4 | 9 |
| 5 | 5 | 10 |
| 5 | 6 | 11 |
| 6 | 1 | 7 |
| 6 | 2 | 8 |
| 6 | 3 | 9 |
| 6 | 4 | 10 |
| 6 | 5 | 11 |
| 6 | 6 | 12 |

we can see that the value '7' for sum appears most frequently. If we plotted the frequency distribution of the sum, it would look something like this:

```
               x
            x  x  x
         x  x  x  x  x  
      x  x  x  x  x  x  x 
   x  x  x  x  x  x  x  x  x
x  x  x  x  x  x  x  x  x  x  x

2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10 11 12
```

Therefore, we can assume that a truly random selection of this dataset will follow this distribution pattern. What I'm interested in is psuedo-random DISTINCT selection of N rows that attempts to normalize the distribution based on the sum column.

E.g.,

```
SELECT * FROM dice_rolls ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 5;
```

is what I have now. This query is most likely to contain rows where the sum is 5, 6, 7, 8, 9. How would I go about using a custom ORDER BY function that would be significantly more likely (or even *strictly*) to, return rows where the sum has an even chance of being 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, or 12?

Answer (score 0):

Get a CTE with the different sums, pick one and return a matching row:

```
WITH sums AS (
   SELECT DISTINCT dice_sum FROM dice_rolls
)
SELECT * FROM dice_rolls
WHERE dice_sum = (SELECT dice_sum FROM sums ORDER BY random() LIMIT 1)
ORDER BY random() LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: If I were to change the LIMIT 1 in both places to LIMIT 5, will 5 dice_sums come back that are distinct using WHERE IN instead? Or each with an even chance of being selected? No, right? I think maybe I am looking for a more complicated WHERE clause in this case? I'm going to keep researching; I'll accept this answer if I don't find anything else as this does return at least one row, thanks!